# @Return_Value is always -1

Tags: c#, return-value

I have a big problem getting `@RETURN_VALUE` parameter when          call an     stored procedure in C# QueriesTableAdapter and VS 2015 service pack 3.  I connect my project directly to an stored proc existent into SQL server 2012.

This method works fine using input or output parameters BUT retrieving `@return_value` do not work (is a Vs BUG?).  Debbuging I noticed in the class the `Command.Parameter[0]` as `@RETURN_VALUE`

Any Idea?, I need to use these stored without modifications because they are used by other applications and `@return_value` is very important.

Thank you for help

```
int returnValue;
try {
    returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //returnValue is Always -1!
}
finally {
    if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You handle the parameter the wrong way.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) `ExecuteNonQuery` returns:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command.When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers.For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.

So -1 is correct and you will never get any calculated result that way.

Correct usage of output parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;    
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for reply. The stored proc I call do a SELECT statements and it has no triggers. Anyway, I'm using automatic code creation for the queries and then, I don't know how to add the parameter you said. Do you mean to modify datasetname.xsd file where there is the full code?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understood what you mean. I have a big problem because I need to use the RETURN statement value inside the stored proc because other application (DELPHI) manages it in other way ... :-(  Big problem for me. Thank you a lot for your help. I learnt a very useful info.

Comment: then it sould go the proposed way

Comment: I musn't modify the stored procedure code to add a new output parameter